# Getting the last 7 rows from MySQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the last 7 records from a table whose records were entered by the user

Here is my query:

```
$database->setQuery("SELECT * FROM #__mytable WHERE (user_id = '$uid')");
$dberr="";
if (!$database->query()) {
    $dberr = $database->getErrorMsg();
}

if(!$dberr==""){
   echo($dberr."<br>");
}else{
   $rows = $database->loadObjectList();
```

How do I cycle thru the $rows to get the last 7?

Comment: I accepted one of the answers, but I do wish the answer included the PHP code.

Comment: You don't need any modification in your PHP code to achieve the discribed effect. Just replace your SQL query in your setQuery parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    #__mytable
WHERE  user_id = '$uid'
ORDER BY
       entered_date DESC
LIMIT 7
```

To get them in ascending order, use:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    #__mytable
        WHERE  user_id = '$uid'
        ORDER BY
               entered_date DESC
        LIMIT 7
        ) q
ORDER BY
        entered_date
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't:

```
SELECT * FROM ... WHERE ... ORDER BY user_id DESC LIMIT 7
```

Comment: Why do you order the resoult by user_id?

Comment: I assumed the user IDs are incremental and unique, and thus would serve well as default clustering order of the whole table. You have to sort by a key, otherwise the results are unpredictable and will vary widely accross platforms/database engines/library versions/phase of the moon.

Comment: `@mst`: `user_id` is filtered on in the original query.

Comment: That's perfectly fine. You can sort by other keys, or by keys that are used in WHERE conditions or the keys (fields) that are omitted from the SELECT statement.

Comment: But to get the last seven, ordering by user_id doesn't make sense.

Comment: "Last 7" can only apply to an ordered list. It makes no sense in any other context. Without an explicit sorting order, "last 7" is identical to "arbitrary 7". I don't know the actual layout of the OP's schema - I merely presume that user_id is a primary key.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM #__mytable WHERE (user_id = '$uid') ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,7
```